# stack overflow when making a third object for merge sort project c++

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison, stack-overflow, mergesort

So I am making a merge sort program in c++ that is supposed to take 5 arrays of size 10, 100, 1000, 10000, and 100000, and tell how many comparisons are made for each array.  I was able to sort all arrays fine, but I ran into a stack overflow when trying to make a third object of my merge sort class. I made the first two objects of my merge sort class without any problems, but when I make a third object of my merge sort class, I get an error that there is a stack overflow.  When I debug the program it points me to the `.asm` file, and since I don't know assembly I'm not sure what to think of this.  I've run into this problem in the past, and it's because I forgot to dynamically allocate memory to array's.  I looked back and all my array's have been dynamically allocated, so I'm not sure why I am getting this error.  Here is my main, I marked what is giving me errors with asterisks.  Any help is appreciated, this is my second question on here so don't destroy me please :)

```
//main.cpp
int main(){
    int* tenArray;
    int* hundArray;
    int* thouArray;
    int* tenThouArray;
    int*oneHundThouArray;
    tenArray = new int[9];
    hundArray = new int[99];
    thouArray = new int[999];
    tenThouArray = new int[9999];
    oneHundThouArray = new int[99999];

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    //Create arrays filled with random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_TEN; i++) {
        tenArray[i] = rand();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_HUND; i++) {
        hundArray[i] = rand();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_THOU; i++) {
        thouArray[i] = rand();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_TEN_THOU; i++) {
        tenThouArray[i] = rand();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_ONE_HUND_THOU; i++) {
        oneHundThouArray[i] = rand();
    } 

    MergeSort tenSort;
    MergeSort hundSort;
    //******************************************************************
    MergeSort thouSort;//When typed the program will give an error
    //******************************************************************    

    //Here I am just calling my sort function from implementation file:
    //sorting 10 array
    tenSort.sort(tenArray, 0, ARRAY_TEN - 1);
    cout << endl << "Comparisons = " << tenSort.getCount() << endl;

    //sorting 100 array
    hundSort.sort(hundArray, 0, ARRAY_HUND - 1);
    cout << endl << "Comparisons = " << hundSort.getCount() << endl; 

    //****************************************************************
    //sorting thousand array  
    thouSort.sort(thouArray, 0, ARRAY_THOU - 1);
    cout << "comparison = " << thouSort.getCount() << endl;
    //****************************************************************
}
```

getCount just looks like this:

```
//in implementation
int MergeSort::getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

If it helps the line in the asm file causing the error says:

```
test     dword ptr[eax],eax    ;probe page
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the MergeSort constructors allocate any additional memory? It's possible you're actually running out of memory on the stack. The stack can only contain so much data, and declaring over a hundred-thousand integers multiple times could add up to quite a lot.

Comment: no my MergeSort constructor only sets my counter to 0, it doesn't do any allocating at all.  So I should have my constructor allocate additional memory?  I've never had a problem doing 100,000 before

Comment: thanks for your comment it pointed me in the right direction.  I needed to allocate memory for the object's themselves by doing: MergeSort *tenSort = new MergeSort();